# How to manage email with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, email

I've a SharePoint Foundation 2013 solution installed on my server.

Many of our users use email to share documents and, most of all, to receive file (docx, pdf, images) from external users.

These email inboxes are hosted in on another server (I don't have administrator access to this server, just pop3/imap/smtp parameters).

So, I'm searching a way to give to my users a common interface (in SharePoint) to check their emails and, maybe, to save attachments to DL etc. I've seen that OWA can be integrated in SP having an Exchange Server, but I don't own this.

Actually I would be really happy just having a sort of webmail working with SP or integrated in SP. With the possibility to send and receive email from different email addresses.

Does anyone know a good solution for this? (if exists)